# getting result from php to android

Tags: php, android, mysqli

Problem Solved!!!

I am posting my php file and android class below. 
The problem is when I try to check the result returned from the php, it's giving me lots of rubbish data.

loginStatus.php

```
    <?php
$mysql = new mysqli("10.0.0.2", "root", "nishad0963", "cabService");

if($mysql->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to connect to DB"; 
}   
//echo $mysql->host_info . "\n";

$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query_select = $mysql->query("SELECT status FROM loginStatus WHERE userName = 'nishad' and password = 'password' ");

//echo $query_select;

while(($row = $query_select->fetch_assoc())!=null);
{
    printf("result = %s", $row["status"]);
}

$mysql->close();

?>
```

signInActivity.java

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class signInActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {


        //preparing data
        String data = null;
        String userName = (String) arg0[0];
        String password = (String) arg0[1];
        try {
            data = URLEncoder.encode("userName", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("DATA_ERROR", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //making connection
        String url_address = "http://10.0.0.2/cabService/loginStatus.php";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_address);
            URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
            Log.d("Progress Status", "It's working");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            //reading response
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String Line;
            while((Line = br.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(Line);
                Log.d("Result Status", Line);
            }
            return sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("URL_ERROR", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("URL_CONNECTION_ERROR", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }




        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(result.equals(1)){
            Log.d("LOGIN_SUCCESS", result);
        }
        else
            Log.d("LOGIN_FAILURE", result);
    }


}
```

logcat of debugging

```
   01-03 16:42:52.102: D/Status(626): Before Clicking
01-03 16:42:52.452: D/Progress Status(626): It's working
01-03 16:42:52.532: D/Result Status(626): result =
```

result status is the tag for returned result.

Hope u can help!
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

I think the error is with the PHP file.

edit:

mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText userName, passWord;
    private Button loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);    
    passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEdit);

    final String name = userName.getText().toString();
    final String password = passWord.getText().toString();

    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d("Status","Before Clicking");
            new signInActivity().doInBackground(name, password);

        }
    });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Look at the parameters being passed by asyncTask. I m pretty sure it's not correct.

Comment: cant you return those $data[] = $row; as json to android?

Comment: I dont want to use JSON. I tried them before but it was a lot of hassle. This way seems better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat output states it; line 9 of `loginStatus.php`:

```
Function name must be a string.
```

You are accessing the super global `$_POST`, which is an array using the function call syntax
`$_POST('user')`  instead of `$_POST['user']`. Because php allows function calls based on strings, `$myfuncname ="someFunc";` `$myfuncname();` and `$_POST` is not a string but an array you get this error message.

Comment: thanks a lot. Solved that problem but now I am not getting any response from my DB. I have updated the logcat and the PHP code. Please have a look. @peter & jbihan.

Comment: Okay, I m receiving data from db fine. 
There's some problem in data being passed to AsyncTask. Strings from the mainActivity is not received by AsyncTask. I have given mainAcitivity.java.

Comment: Okay, this could be an issue mentioned in another thread dealing with inputstreams. Your call to printf doesn't include newlines on which readLine relies. Try adding printf("result = %s\n", $row["status"]);

Answer (score 0):

The same was done using the script in the following link this should help.

- [How to create Simple Login form using php in android? – Connect php
  with android.](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/22/create-simple-login-form-php-android-connect-php-android/)

Comment: what is the value in the column returned?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question. Pleas take a look.